# java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I am getting a java.io.UncheckedIOException when running `mvn package` or `mvn clean install` on mvn project.

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.lazy(Locations.java:712)
```

I am not sure what the issue is with my jdk as its perfectly okay for other gradle based projects.

Using maven 3.6.0. full log here

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 27 source files to workspace/travelapi/travel-client/target/classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (9-internal). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.lazy(Locations.java:712)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.isDefault(Locations.java:546)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.isDefaultBootClassPath(Locations.java:126)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager.isDefaultBootClassPath(BaseFileManager.java:204)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.validate(Arguments.java:479)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.prepareCompiler(JavacTaskImpl.java:168)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.access$000(JavacTaskImpl.java:69)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$1.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$1.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:93)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:128)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:93)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:87)
        at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler$1.call(BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler.java:99)
        at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneCompiler.run(BaseErrorProneCompiler.java:137)
        at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneCompiler.run(BaseErrorProneCompiler.java:108)
        at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.run(ErrorProneCompiler.java:119)
        at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.compile(ErrorProneCompiler.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.errorprone.JavacCompilerWithErrorProne$CompilerInvoker.compile(JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.java:219)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.errorprone.JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.performCompile(JavacCompilerWithErrorProne.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:407)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:471)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3694)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.systemClasses(Locations.java:665)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.computePath(Locations.java:621)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.lazy(Locations.java:709)
        ... 46 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for travel 1.20.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] travel ............................................ SUCCESS [  4.072 s]
[INFO] travel-client ..................................... FAILURE [  1.903 s]
[INFO] travel-service .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.696 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-18T10:44:56+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project travel-client: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :travel-client
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? And please show the full log output ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I have updated the question with the logs

Comment: First upgrade you maven-compiler-plugin to the most recent one  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

Comment: I am getting the same exception, if anyone found a solution, please share.